# C++ shared_ptr and reading from the class

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have a problem with simple reading from the file that shares file pointer between a few objects (It works for me with just simple istream, but not when I am using shared pointer of istream pointers).

I am trying to read the whole file to the buffer (file itself is a few lines long.

The code compiles, but throws segmentation fault.

The class that uses shared_ptr:

```
RecordsSplitter::RecordsSplitter(char *filename):iStream( new ifstream(filename, ifstream::in|ifstream::binary))
{
}


string RecordsSplitter::buildRecord() {
       char *buffer;
        int buffer_length;
        iStream->seekg (0, ios::end)_
        buffer_length = iStream->tellg();
        cout << buffer_length;
        iStream->seekg(0, ios::beg);
        iStream->read(buffer,buffer_length);
        iStream->close();
        cout << buffer;

        return 0;
}







int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        RecordsSplitter *splitter;
        splitter = new RecordsSplitter(argv[2]);
        int return_num = splitter->buildRecord();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't see any `shared_ptr` in your code.

Comment: where do you initialize your buffer?

Comment: Do not write C++ code like this: all your pointers and uses of `new` are redundant. Use plain objects instead of pointers. Your code is error-prone and complicated.

Comment: "The code compiles, but throws segmentation fault." Could you paste the code that compiles? The code you pasted doesn't. It is both incomplete and incorrect. Please provide a minimal, complete program that demonstrates the error you see. For information about how to produce a minimal complete sample program, and why producing it is a good idea, see http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 0):

You declare your buffer but you don't initialise it anywhere.
You need this in your `buildRecord` function or a use of malloc if you so desire.

```
buffer = new char[buffer_length];
```

Your seg fault is caused by this uninitialised pointer

Don't forget to clean up!

```
delete[] buffer;
```

Comment: Or better yet, `char buffer[buffer_length]`.

Comment: @Travis: C++ doesn't have variable-length arrays.

Comment: @Travis, I suppose you could have that if: `const int buffer_length = iStream->tellg();` was there

Comment: @interjay: True, by the standard. But every compiler I use supports them.

Comment: @tom502: Correct...other things would have to be changed, but compared to the memleak that is happening with this simple fix, I would say it is an improvement.

Comment: @Travis: Apparently you don't use a lot of compilers then. MS Visual C++ doesn't support VLAs, and I believe Intel's compiler doesn't either.

Comment: @interjay: gcc, clang and Intel C++ all do.

Comment: @Travis: Intel compiler on Windows doesn't support it, only on Linux where it has gcc compatibility. This is really a gcc feature, not a C++ feature.